# Link in React Router won't let me navigate as expected

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have an app that allows you to navigate

`/user`=>`/user/userid`

once I'm on `user/userid` I want to create links to `/reports/reportid`

I'm using this code

```js
function ReportItem({ report }) {
    const to = `reports/${report.id}`

    return (
        <li className='user'>
            <Link to={to}>{report.date}</Link>
        </li>
    )
}
```

However this results in me navigating to `/users/reports/reportid` instead of `/reports/reportid`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I think you are missing a `/`. Assigning `/reports/${report.id}` to `to` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kluddizz comment is the correct solution. I just need to update the config to prefix a `/` as shown below

```js
function ReportItem({ report }) {
    const to = `/reports/${report.id}` // <=== prefixed a / to fix issue

    return (
        <li className='user'>
            <Link to={to}>{report.date}</Link>
        </li>
    )
}
```